# Tangent plane and normal line

Tags: calculus

Find the equation of the tangent plane and the vectorial equation of the normal line of the surface

$$z = x^2 + y^2$$

at the point $(1,-2,5)$

For the vectorial equation of the normal line, should I consider the function $F(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 -z$ and $\vec{n} = \vec{\nabla}F(1,-2,5)$ as my normal vector?

I'm not sure of how should I do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The surface

$z = x^2 + y^2 \tag{1}$

is in fact the level surface of the function

$F(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 -z \tag{2}$

on which $F(x, y, z)$ takes the value $0$.  Since the gradient of a differentiable function is normal to its level surfaces, we can indeed obtain a normal to (1) by computing the gradient of $F(x, y, z)$ as given by (2).  We have

$\nabla F(x, y, z) = (2x, 2y, -1) \tag{3}$

at any point $(x, y, z) \in \Bbb R^3$; thus, at the point $(1, -2, 5)$, which is easily seen to lie in the surface

$F(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 - z = 0, \tag{4}$

($1^2 + (-2)^2 -5 = 0$) we have

$\nabla F(1, -2, 5) = (2, -4, -1). \tag{5}$

Now, I'm not exactly sure what it means to represent a line in vectorial form, but an expression for the line normal to the surface $z = x^2 + y^2$ at the point $(1, -2, 5)$ may now be written in terms of the normal vector $\vec n = \nabla F(1, -2, 5)$ and the position vector field $\vec r= (x, y, z)$ on $\Bbb R^3$; taking $\vec r_0 = (1, -2, 5)$, we have

$\vec r(t) = \vec r_0 + t\nabla F(1,2,5), \tag{6}$

or

$\vec r(t) = (1, -2, 5) + t(2, -4, -1). \tag{7}$

An expression for the tangent plane may be had in a roughly similar manner; $\vec r = (x, y, z)$ is a point in the tangent plane if and only if the vector $\vec r - \vec r_0$ lies in that plane and is hence perpendicular to $\nabla F(1, -2, 5)$; thus we may write

$(\vec r - \vec r_0) \cdot \nabla F(1, -2, 5) = (\vec r - \vec r_0) \cdot (2, -4, -1) =0 \tag{8}$

for the equation of the (tangent) plane passing through the point $\vec r_0 = (1, -2, 5)$.  A little algebra allows (8) to be re-written in another well-known form:

$2x -4y - z = \vec r_0 \cdot (2, -4, -1) = (1, -2, 5) \cdot (2, -4, -1) = 5. \tag{9}$

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 2):

(1)You have a function $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z$, now to find the tangent plane of $f$ at $P=(1,-2,5)$ you want to first compute the $\nabla(f(p))$, which is the gradient of $f$ at $P$. Well the $$\nabla(f)=(2x,2y,-1) \implies \nabla(f(1,-2,5))=(2,-4,-1).$$

Now, you have your normal vector and you want to find a plane perpendicular to $N=\nabla(f(1,-2,5))=(2,-4,-1)$ that goes through $P$.

Solve,
\begin{align*}
(X-P)\cdot N=0 &\implies X\cdot N = P\cdot N \\
&\implies (x,y,z)\cdot (2,-4,-1) = (1,-2,5)\cdot (2,-4,-1) \\
&\implies 2x-4y-z=2+8-5 \\
&\implies 2x-4y-z=5
\end{align*} and this is your tangent plane.

(2) Now for the vectorial equation I assume you want a parametric line? So, $$P+tA=(1,-2,5)+t(2,-4,-1).$$

Comment: @ 3.1416:  you flipped the sign of the $z$-component of $grad(f(1 -2, 5)$ at the end of your first paragraph!

Comment: thanks a lot @RobertLewis, you deserve credit for this then.

Comment: @ 3.1416:  glad to help out, and thanks for the kind words.  I was glad to see our answers agreed.  Corroboration warms the heart!  Cheers.